# Match content of the two child div horizontally inside one parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have one child div inside one parent div like this

```
<div id="parent" style="background-color: #75941f;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px outset #4f6417;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;height:100%;width:100%;">

     <div id="child1" style="float:left;width:50%;text-align:center"></div>
     <div id="child2" style="float:right;width:50%;text-align:center"></div>

</div>
```

I am using `jquery` to put objects as well as the image of the number in both of the child div using

```
var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
        i;
function getImage(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "apple_transparent.gif"
    img.width = 80;
    img.height=80;

    return img;
}
for (i=0; i<rand1; i++){
    $("#child1").append(getImage());
$('#child1').append('<img id="theImg" src="numbers/' + rand1 + '.png" width="260px" height="260px"/>');
```

Following the same process above i am putting objects in my other div also.But my problem is if `rand1` variable puts 7 objects in `child1` and `rand2` variable puts 2 objects in `child2` then how can i match both the div's object's image as well as the objects in level to each other?

Comment: Is that about you need two div with same image..?

Comment: what do you mean by "match both the div's object's image as well as the objects in level to each other", an example drawing would help.

Comment: @WebDevron Yes i have used the same image in both the child div.

Comment: @SariAlalem I want to show those 2 object in one div in line with the 7 objects of another child div. And while showing the Number showing in both the div will also be in the line

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused. You did not close the parent div tag after style.

Comment: yes it will be closed

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish and the JS code above seems incomplete,with this line having errors: $("#child1")imgContainer.append(getImage());

Comment: @SariAlalem Sorry its my mistake i have editted  my question

Comment: What is the purpose of appending a number of `rand1` of the same transparent image to the first child `div`? If you want to make both the child divs have the same width, I think there is another more direct and cleaner solution.